# apex:actionsupport rerender issue with two required fields

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component

I need to have two required fields as lookup input field (one for account and one for contact) in a single pageblocksection section.
On selection of each lookup, a particular section is getting rendered.
When there is only  one required field, both the rerendering is happening properly.
When I make both the fields required, the first lookup selection rerendering is not happening (which ever I chose first)
I have no idea where is the problem. Please help.
Thanks,

Comment: Could you please post your code?

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue and the solution at https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F0000000965kIAA

Only when I clubbed the two required input fields for action into two separate action regions, the re-render happens as expected.

Thanks All!